# Get location of game object relative to MapBox map real world location

Tags: unity-game-engine, geolocation, mapbox

I have a [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) game object which can be moved around on top of a [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) layer. How do I get the real world location of the game object related to the visual location on the map?

Comment: Don't know if you check [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/195). But might help you

Comment: @EmreE I just had a look a it, but it is about how to convert between two coordinate formats. I want to fint the real world coordinate of my game object.

Comment: by real world coordinate, do you mean; You will get the **transform.position** of the gameObject and convert it to lat /long ? Like in google maps where you make a long click on map and it displays at the bottom of the screen ? I thought the info in the link seemed similar to me @Sulby

Comment: Also this [extensions](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-unity-sdk/api/unity/Mapbox.Unity.Utilities.VectorExtensions.html) have similar examples about your case. @Sulby